# Electron.NET "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: electron, electron.net

I mainly developed this app using IIS Express for testing (Faster to start than Electron). Now when I try and run it in Electron.NET using `electronize start`, almost all of my server-side resources are refusing my connection. I've tried looking around for the cause of this but I've not found anything.

Any suggestions?

One of the resources I'm trying to access

```css
 background-image: url("https://localhost:5001/Home/MissingTexture");
```

Another resource

```
GET https://localhost:44338/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```